# Accessing others outlook using python with ID and Password

Tags: python, outlook

How can we modify the below code to connect to outlook mail using ID and Password of another user using python

```
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)         
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetLast()
body_content = message.body
print body_content
```

Comment: You can't - the code above assumes there is a pre-configured profile in Outlook. Unless the mailbox in question is added to the existing profile, the user name and password won't help you, especially if the mailbox requires MFA authentication. Where is the mailbox hosted?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Logon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.logon) method if the user's profile is configured in Outlook. Otherwise in case of O365 accounts you may consider using EWS (see [Explore the EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/explore-the-ews-managed-api-ews-and-web-services-in-exchange)), Outlook REST API or Graph API. Read more about that in the [Overview of Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview) article.